# How to make an xpath result into a string with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, string, xpath

```
if($xmlobj = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xml_feed)))
{
    $result = $xmlobj->xpath("TrafficMeta");
}
```

The above code returns the desired result and when viewed with print_r it shows this, which is what I want to get (sessionId):

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [sessionId] => tbfm1t45xplzrongbtbdyfa5 ) )
```

How can I make this sessionId into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects. To access the $sessionId member of the first array entry you do this:

```
echo $result[0]->sessionId;
```

Note that there might be more elements in the array, though. You should either assert that there is really exactly one or process all of them:

```
# either one of these
assert(count($result) === 1);
if (count($result) !== 1) throw new Exception('Unexpected data in xml');
# or this
foreach ($result as $object) {
    echo $object->sessionId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help soulmerge, appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it to work using XPath, but `$result[0]['sessionId']` works fine. Use `strval()` on it if you need a real string.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$result[0]->sessionId`.